# Can an object "go by", meaning that it vanishes? (example)

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

Reading another story from C.A. Smith, I found the following sentence:

> Of my birth, my youth, and the appelation by which I was known and
> perhaps renowned among men, it would now be bootless to speak: for
> those days are one in remoteness with the reign of Al Raschid, **they
> have gone by like the Afrit-builded halls of Suleiman**.

I am not sure about the meaning here, as the phrase using "go by" does not make much sense to me. Probably if the halls were extremely large and one was moving along them, maybe this would make more sense, but as it is, I do not really know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage is a bit unusual or non-standard, although there is enough information in context to make it clear.

Depending on the context, "go by" can refer to something that disappears in time (meaning "vanishing into the past") or space ("vanishing into the distance"). You can see some examples in Cambridge dictionaries under ["go by"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-by). It's commonly used of everyday objects moving away in space (e.g. "a train going by"). When talking about time, it's generally used with subjects like "time", "days", "years", or other measures of time, for example: "As time goes by", "years went by".

The example talks of "those days...have gone by" which matches this usage, and is totally normal. But Smith also talks about buildings (the halls of Suleiman) that have "gone by", meaning "vanishing into the past". This usage is not standard today (it might have been more common when Smith was writing although I can't find evidence of that). The meaning is clear from the context (by analogy with "those days").

It might be more natural to say something slightly different like: "those days are long gone, like the halls of Suleiman".

Comment: I like to say "one with Nineveh and Tyre" which does earn me odd looks sometimes.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey a good one to add is ‘gone the way of Constantinople’.

Comment: I read “they have gone by” as referring to “those days”, and “those days have gone by” is totally normal.

Comment: Far-called, our navies melt away;
   On dune and headland sinks the fire:
Lo, all our pomp of yesterday
   Is one with Nineveh and Tyre!
Judge of the Nations, spare us yet,
Lest we forget—lest we forget!

Comment: Makes me shiver still. Kipling, my guilty pleasure.